# Regex match > Skip optional string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the URL from the below RTF in C#:

```
HYPERLINK https://google.com \\\\o MyLink}}
HYPERLINK {\\plain\\ltrch\\f0\\fs24\\ltrch\\f1\\fs22\\cf1\\ulnone\\ulc1 tel://777 \\\\o MyLink}}}
```

Expected result:
    https://google.com
    tel://777

So far: `HYPERLINK\s{?.*?\s?(.*?)\s.*?MyLink`

But the second pattern does not match, see here:

https://regex101.com/r/AUDpbg/1

Comment: Can the RTF be really parsed correctly using RegEx? Wouldn't there be the same issues like in parsing XML/HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to search for consecutive non-space characters which contain `<alphabetical>://`:

```
HYPERLINK.*?(\w+:\/\/\S+).*MyLink
```

https://regex101.com/r/AUDpbg/3

Comment: RTF is a mark up text, `.*?` may grab too much, your `\S+:\/\/\S+` may get matched outside of a HYPERLINK.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax, but I'm guessing that if multiple `HYPERLINK`s can appear on one line, I would need to make sure not to match a `}}` in between?

Comment: It does not really matter if there are multiple HYPERLINKs on a line, there may be `\w+://\S+` somewhere outside of the HYPERLINK block. Maybe `HYPERLINK\s*(?:{[^\s}]+)?\s*([^\s}]+)[^}]*MyLink` would be  safer regex. I do not say your won't work, but it is just a bad idea to use `.` when parsing markup text. Especially some other text in between 2 strings.